# Summing a column value with each row value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2011

I want to add a column value with each row value in an excel. I would insert an image of my spreadsheet but apparently I need 10 reputation to do that.

Basically, it would be the following:

Cell B2 = B1+A2

Cell B3 = B1+A3

Cell B4 = B1+A4

and so on.

I can do that for one column but I need to replicate it in each column.

Can anyone please tell me what formula/method I could use? Dragging doesn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried blocking the range with dollar signs? like B2 = $B$1+A2 and then dragging?

Comment: Use `$` for absolute reference. For example, if you copy `=B$1+A2` from row 2 to row 5, row 5 will have `=B$1+A5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cell `B2` put:

```
=$A2 + B$1
```

Then drag down, and then drag across.